# Reading Nietzsche in Russian vs. in English

Tags: nietzsche, translation

Once I read article about how bad Russian translations of Nietzsche's works & how they misinterpret the original saying. Reading it in German would be just great, and I'm looking to learn German, but I really need Nietzsche now and don't want to delay it anymore. Well, my English is good enough to read "Contact" by Sagan, but philosophy is another. Not parsing one sentence could result in misinterpreting a lot of important things. So I'm not sure if reading it in non-native language is a good idea.

Also I'm not sure which one of his works will suite my needs better, so I'm open to your advices. I'm 18 now and I'm in hard process of building my understanding of this world and finding my place there. My whole life I was atheist but recently I started to think about Christianity, thus I wanted to revert back on roots and to read some existentialist literature. Because I read Nietzsche's "Gay Science" when I was 11 and I think it influenced me a lot.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Philosophy.SE. Please try to avoid inviting opinions. If you ask for advice, you have to determine very narrowly what your needs are so that there is an actual answer available instead of "oh well, there are many possibilities, but I like this most". As part of the StackExchange network, we try to avoid discussions and opinions in favour of well-defined questions with equally well-defined answers (even if this is quite hard considering the topic of philosophy).

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking understood, I could add more information about what I need to read it for so that it would be more specific, but am afraid it becomes a whole another question.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking done.